# How to install nautilus in Ubuntu 16

Tags: nautilus

how to install Nautilus on ubuntu 16? I current have sudo apt-get install nautilus but it is failing.

Comment: Nautilus should be installed by default, unless you uninstalled it it should be there. When you say "but it is failing", what exactly do you mean? Please [edit] your question to provide any error messages you see or reason to believe that it is failing.

Comment: An Ubuntu Server system, a minimal system (mini.iso), and Ubuntu Core have no graphical interface installed by default, so they don't come with Nautilus preinstalled. And many [official derivatives of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) don't use Nautilus. Are you using one of those? Are you sure Nautilus is not installed? (Please explain.) Why are you trying to install it? How is it failing? Have you run any other commands, like `sudo apt update` first? If not, what happens when you do that? What is going wrong; in particular, what are the *complete* error messages?

Comment: Personally I don't think this question deserves to get "unclear" or "un useful" since it is my question to and searching on Google get me to this post, afterward I noticed that Nautilus is preinstalled on Ubuntu 16, as Kuntal Majumder mentioned in his answer to this question! So I'm gonna to give this question some credit :)

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus is preinstalled in Ubuntu , so no need to install it.